# Query places that have common tags in database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a SQLIte database with tables for places and tables for tags,

```
CREATE TABLE places (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(256), 
    address VARCHAR(256),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE tags (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I also have a third table to map the associations between the first two,

```
CREATE TABLE placestags (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    placeid INTEGER, 
    tagid INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(placeid) REFERENCES places (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(tagid) REFERENCES tags (id)
)
```

I can grab which places are tagged with which tags with the following command,

```
SELECT places.id, places.name, tags.id, tags.name
FROM (placestags INNER JOIN places on placestags.placeid = places.id
           INNER JOIN tags on tags.id = placestags.tagid)
WHERE placestags.tagid=tags.id
```

Which will return something like this,

```
id | name          | id | name
---------------------------------          
1  | McDonalds     | 1  | Burgers
2  | Pizza Hut     | 2  | Pizza
3  | Burger King   | 1  | Burgers
```

I am wondering if it is possible to construct a query such that it returns the names of places which share two or more tags. For example, if `McDonalds` and `Burger King` shared both the tags `Burgers` and `Fries`, then I'd like to list that out like this,

```
p1id | p1name      | p2id | p2name      | t1id | t1name        | t2id | t2name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------          
1    | McDonalds   | 3    | Burger King | 1    | Burgers       | 3    | Fries
```

Is this possible with SQL?

Comment: Are you trying to find places that share known tags (e.g, 'what places have the tags burgers and fries?') or trying to return results to help see a correlation?

Comment: I'm actually trying to return results to help see a correlation. I'd upvote an answer on how to solve the former problem of 'what places have the tags burgers and fries' though.

Comment: I think that solving the latter problem would probably help me solve the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query to produce results below:

```
select p1.name, p2.name, t.name
from places p1
join placestags pt1 on p1.id=pt1.placeid
join placestags pt2 on pt1.tagid=pt2.tagid and pt2.placeid <> p1.id
join places p2 on pt2.placeid=p2.id
join tags t on t.id=pt1.tagid
order by p1.id, t.id
```

This does not get everything into a single row like you wanted (you'd need a pivot for that, and I don't think sqlite has it), but it lets you see what is going on. Here is what you'd get from this query:

```
Place1      |   Place2       | Shared_Tag
------------|----------------|-----------
McDonalds       Burger King     Burgers
McDonalds       Burger King     Fries
Burger King     McDonalds       Burgers
Burger King     McDonalds       Fries
```

**EDIT** (in response to a comment):

If you are looking to shorten the query time, try reducing the number of joins, and remove the symmetric duplicates, like this:

```
select pt1.placeid, pt2.placeid, pt1.tagid
from placestags pt1
join placestags pt2 on pt1.tagid=pt2.tagid and pt2.placeid > pt1.placeid
order by pt1.placeid, pt1.tagid
```

Comment: There should be a way to add an exclusion to the join to remove the duplicate rows...

Comment: @NWest Strictly speaking, this query does not return duplicates: it returns its answers once for each side, and because the question is symmetric, each answer is returned twice. You can eliminate one of these symmetric sides by replacing the `<>` operator with `>` or `<`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to run it and my computer just sat there processing. This seems like a very costly query. Is there a way to limit the dataset?

Comment: @awfullyjohn I added a shortened version that brings back only IDs, and drop symmetric results.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks! It works.. It's just *incredibly* slow. Like  7 hours slow. I have about 20,000 places, 40,000 tags, and 260,000 connections between tags and places. I guess I have some database optimizations to do. Any advice?

Comment: @awfullyjohn The numbers do not look *that* big, so I would try the usual suspect first: a missing index on `placestags` (you should have two indexes, one on each column, for this query to work at a reasonable speed). If that does not help, I'd try a DB engine that is faster than SQLite on large data sets (Oracle, SQL Server, DB/2, etc.)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ohhhh. Could you please elaborate on the missing index? Two indexes, how and why?

Comment: @awfullyjohn This query compares `tagid` of `placestags` to `tagid` of other rows in `placestags`. If there is no index, SQLite must scan all 260,000 rows to find a match; if there is an index, SQLite gets the row that it is looking for by scanning only that index, which is several orders of magnitude smaller. Same goes for the check on the `placeid` column. You can create an index using this command: `create index if not exists placestags_tagid_idx on placestags(tagid)`. An index on `placeid` is created in a similar way.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you! That helps a bunch. I can't believe I didn't learn the concept of indexes... I've been following tutorials for Pylons and Django in Python and they create data models using SQL engines... I am only now beginning to get into the SQL itself and work directly on the database. Thanks again, really appreciate it. Do you have any tutorials or resources you'd recommend I'd read, by the way?

Comment: @awfullyjohn Unfortunately, I do not know of any good tutorial: I worked for a few years with a former Oracle guy (he wrote [this book](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Tuning-Dan-Tow/dp/0596005733) on SQL tuning) and I learned most of what I know about DB optimizations from him. His book is very good, too - it is not specific to any single RDBMS engine, and the rules are easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't solve the "find correlations" problem but since you also kind of asked for this...

sqlite does support intersect so you can do the following. If we know two tags, we can find the intersect of the tags we want. It is not pretty and may not be something for the long term but if you are just trying to get an idea of your data, it could be helpful.

Assuming we have two tags with id's 1 & 2:

```
SELECT places.name FROM places 
  INNER JOIN placestags ON places.id=placestags.placeid 
  WHERE placestags.tagid = 1 
INTERSECT 
SELECT places.name FROM places 
  INNER JOIN placestags ON places.id=placestags.placeid 
  WHERE placestags.tagid = 2;
```